# Log to a file the traceback in the same form as the standard Python traceback display

Tags: python, exception, logging, traceback

I'd like to log to a file the traceback of any error in the *exact same form as the standard Python traceback display*, plus the datetime.

This nearly works:

```
import sys, traceback, time
    
def exc_handler(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    with open('mylog.log', 'a') as f:
        dt = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        f.write(f"{dt}\n")
        traceback.print_tb(tb, file=f)
        # traceback.print_exception(ex, tb=None, value="", file=f)  # another approach, doesn't work either
        f.write(f"{dt}\n")

sys.excepthook = exc_handler

def function1():
    1/0

def function2():
    function1()

function2()
```

except that the exception name is not displayed, and other similar little differences ("Traceback..." is not written).

How to have the exact *same format* as the default Python exception traceback display?

Example:

```
2022-10-19 11:19:18
  File "D:\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    function2()
  File "D:\main.py", line 16, in function2
    function1()
  File "D:\main.py", line 13, in function1
    1/0
2022-10-19 11:19:18
```

Here is how it should be logged:

```
2022-10-19 11:19:18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\main.py", line 18, in <module>
    function2()
  File "D:\main.py", line 16, in function2
    function1()
  File "D:\main.py", line 13, in function1
    1/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
2022-10-19 11:19:18
```

Notes:

- if possible, I don't want to include my whole code in a global big `try: except:` block, I prefer an exception handler on top, and then the usual code without a big `try: except:` block.
- I've already read [How to log error to file, and not fail on exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3383865/how-to-log-error-to-file-and-not-fail-on-exception) and similar questions, but here it's not the exact same display as usual traceback display

Comment: The timestamp doesn't seem to be in your second example at all. What output do you want? Do you just want to [print the whole exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception) instead of the traceback?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated. I would like to log in the file the exact same thing (traceback etc.) you would see usually displayed + datetimes.

Comment: So did you try using `print_exception` instead of the method that just gives you the traceback part?

Comment: @jonrsharpe with `traceback.print_exception(ex, tb=None, value="", file=f)` instead of mine it doesn't work, it only prints "str". https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.print_exception

Comment: What do you mean? Give a [mre] of that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The first code black of my question + the line 7 replaced by `traceback.print_exception(ex, tb=None, value="", file=f)`. Thanks! See my edited question's first code block.

Comment: No, don't just describe it - show the thing that _should_ work, not (or not _only_) the thing that's clearly not going to (or rather, the thing that's working as documented but doing something you say you don't want).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't understand your comment, I included this in my various code blocks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have a solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/74123501/1422096) but maybe we can do nicer than `''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb))`. Any idea about this?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make it work with `traceback.print_tb` or `traceback.print_exception`, it was not exactly the same format.

This works (the datetime is only written once, this is ok):

```
import logging, sys, traceback

logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', filemode='a', format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('logger')
sys.excepthook = lambda exctype, value, tb: logging.error(''.join(traceback.format_exception(exctype, value, tb)))  # don't use logger.exception: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28302786

# or, simpler, without the traceback module:
sys.excepthook = lambda exctype, value, tb: logging.error("", exc_info=(exctype, value, tb))

print("hello")

def function1():
    1/0

def function2():
    function1()

function2()
```

See also this precise answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635362